# Adding "nonce" value to token response of spring authorization server

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am trying to implement authorization server with spring security 5.1. But I have a problem.

I have implemented a custome token enhancer to add **id_token**  in token response to match OIDC scope and it is working fine.

But the problem started when the service provider sent **nonce** parameter as part of authorization request and expecting it to be present in the id_token sent by authorization server. So my question is:

How to access the parameters sent in authorize request in "token_enhancer"?

What I have tried?

I have added a login success-handler and can get the saved authorize request. But I need the same when creating the token.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that you are using a CustomTokenEnhancer, the good news is, that you can get the stored request. Next you know what to do ;)

```
@Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(
      OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, 
      OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        log.debug("Getting nonce param from stored request " + authentication.getOAuth2Request().getRequestParameters().get("nonce"));;
        return  accessToken;
    }
```